# What's wrong with my automounter config?

Tags: smb, automount

So, i am using automounter to connect some smb shares. It was all ok on Mojave. Yesterday i downgraded os to High Sierra with full reinstall. For some reason my shares not connect at all now.

Here is my config:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static

#Sambas
/mnt/server auto_server
```

And my auto_server:

```
public -fstype=smbfs,soft ://(user):(password)@server/public
web -fstype=smbfs,soft ://(user):(password)@server/web
projects -fstype=smbfs,soft ://(user):(password)@server/projects
private -fstype=smbfs,soft ://(user):(password)@server/private
```

If i do something like
`mount_smbfs mount_smbfs //(user):(password)@server/public /mnt/server/public`
It's all ok if i mkdir folders manually.

If i do Go -> Connect to Server -> smb://(user):(password)@server/public It's all ok

So, the problem is only with automounter.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/auto_server
```